# Autohotkey on a remote desktop does not work when I disconnect my local desktop

Tags: autohotkey, remote-desktop

Im am using Autohotkey to rerun Pytest every ten minutes on a Virtual machine offered my Microsoft Azure.
My .ahk script is simple.

```js
loop
{
Send !{F10}
Sleep, 600000
}
```

The script works perfectly while Im connected to the remote desktop. But if I exit the full screen or disconnect from it., it does not work. The Autohotkey keeps on running but for some reason just does not register `Send !{F10}`.It only starts registering it when I connect back on it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Autohotkey not functioning properly on minimized virtual machines](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/26749-running-ahk-with-remote-desktop-minimized/) is an issue that's been around for a while, with

(regarding Virtual Machines):

> RemoteAdmin server process launches a program on request of remote
> user (you). So R.A. is a parent process for AHK. Once you minimize
> your RA session client it signals the RA-server that. RA-server thinks
> now that since the client is minimized it does not need anything and
> to consume CPU power it halts any activity of itself and its child
> processes.
> -[wOxxOm](//autohotkey.com/board/topic/26749-running-ahk-with-remote-desktop-minimized/?p=172751)

And in the documentation of other AHK functions, such as [WinActivate](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm#Remarks)

> Known issue: If the script is running on a computer or server being
> accessed via remote desktop, WinActivate may hang if the remote
> desktop client is minimized. One workaround is to use commands which
> don't require window activation, such as ControlSend and ControlClick.
> Another possible workaround is to apply the following registry setting
> on the local/client computer:
>
> ```
> ; Change HKCU to HKLM to affect all users on this system.
> RegWrite REG_DWORD, HKCU, Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client
>     , RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized, 2
> ```

^^The above registry change may potentially solve your issue as well^^

The forum thread provides a couple of different workarounds for this issue, but if you are just trying to put the VM out of the way while you do other stuff on your computer, the *least gimmicky solution that I can think of* would be to move the Virtual Machine window on the host computer to a Virtual Desktop by either using the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcut or by [using this guide](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-multiple-desktops-windows-10). By moving the window to a virtual desktop, the Virtual Machine will moved out of the way in a manner where it would not be minimized, allowing it to continue running the AHK script. Additionally, you can quickly navigate between Virtual Desktops with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> shortcuts.